# Does SWT FillLayout support laying controls of uneven width horizontally?

Tags: java, layout, swt

I would like to build a horizontal buttonbar using `FillLayout`. However, the layout displays the buttons with even width. I know that I can use `GridLayout` to accomplish my goal. However, I would like to know if the `FillLayout` can achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FillLayout` JavaDoc says:

> FillLayout is the simplest layout class. It lays out controls in a
>   single row or column, **forcing them to be the same size**.

Comment: Thanks, greg-449, for pointing it out. It means that I have to use GridLayout, or others that fit, to achieve what I want then.